# add values to each array in a 2D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm looking for a way to efficiently add a fixed number of `np.nan` values at the beginning of each array in a numpy array of shape (3,123...):

```
Original numpy array:

[[1,2,3...],
 [4,5,6...],
 [7,8,9...]]

New numpy array:

[[nan,nan,1,2,3...],
 [nan,nan,4,5,6...],
 [nan,nan,7,8,9...]]
```

I tried with a for loop:

```py
import numpy as np

original_array = np.random.rand(3,3)
gap = np.empty(shape=(2,))
gap.fill(np.nan)
new_array = np.zeros(shape=(3,5))
for i,row in enumerate(original_array):
    new_array[i] = np.concatenate([gap,row])
```

It works but this is probably not the best way to do it.

Comment: Look at `np.hstack`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use `np.pad`

```
import numpy as np

original_array = np.arange(1, 10).reshape(-1, 3).astype(np.float32)
npad = ((0, 0), (2, 0))
np.pad(original_array,npad,mode='constant',constant_values=(np.nan))
```

Output:

```
array([[nan, nan,  1.,  2.,  3.],
       [nan, nan,  4.,  5.,  6.],
       [nan, nan,  7.,  8.,  9.]], dtype=float32)
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution (thanks to @roganjosh for suggesting the use of [`numpy.full`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.full.html)), which is based on [`numpy.hstack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html):

```
a = np.full((3,2), np.nan)
b = np.arange(1, 10).reshape(-1, 3)
np.hstack((a, b))
```

Output:

```
array([[nan, nan,  1.,  2.,  3.],
       [nan, nan,  4.,  5.,  6.],
       [nan, nan,  7.,  8.,  9.]])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @roganjosh! `np.full`  is much better and I have edited my solution accordingly.